# How can I load data for editing on a ReduxForm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form

I am attempting to load some data on a redux form so I can edit it.
I am already loading it with a reducer apart from the redux form. So first: I don't know if this is the proper way or if redux provides any kind of API for that.

As the data is inmutable, I can not change it, if I try to change the data on any of the inputs, it will always restored the input to its initial value. So I want to know how can I load the form with its values initialized and then find a way to allow me to edit the values so I can send them back to the proper endpoint.

These are the inputs and the way I load the data:

```
class PassengerFormModal extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // HERE I LOAD THE DATA THAT WILL BE PRESENT WHEN THE MODAL IS VISIBLE
    const {
      passengerInfo,
      editPassengerDataActionActionHandler,
    } = this.props;

    if (passengerInfo) {
      editPassengerDataActionActionHandler({
        id: passengerInfo.id,
        phone: passengerInfo.phone,
      });
    }
  }

  const phoneField = () => (
    <TextInput
      onFocus={onFocus}
      value={editPassengerData.phone}
      onChangeText={phone => editPassengerDataActionActionHandler({ phone })}
    />
  );
  ...
  <Field name="phone" component={this.phoneField} /> // Redux Form input
  ...
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={submitForm}
  >
} 

export default compose(
  reduxForm({ form: 'PassengerFormModal' }),
  connect(
    store => ({
      editPassengerData: store.popupsModals.editPassengerData,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      editPassengerDataActionActionHandler: data => {
        dispatch(editPassengerDataAction(data));
      },
    }),
  ),
)(PassengerFormModal);
```

So far, every time the form gets hidden and it is shown again, the values I get from the prop `passengerInfo` are there. But I can not edit them. I have this action handler in the onChangeText of the `TextInput` -> `onChangeText={phone => editPassengerDataActionActionHandler({ phone })}` which I would like to send the edited values to a reducer or, is there a way to do that with redux form?

I've been stuck here for a while on this.

Comment: i believe you are looking for [ReduxForm's initialValues](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/initializefromstate/)?